# Reusable code for $http calls in angular

Tags: angularjs

In all of my controllers I notice I have the same code over and over again after posting data. See below. Is there someway I can just pass my service to some sort of common function and handle everything there.

```
//user submits via click
$scope.submit = function(val) {
            MyService.update(val).then(function(result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    $state.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $state.go('^');
                }
            })
    }
```

Maybe turn this into just

```
$scope.submit = commonFn(MyService.update(val));
```

Any advice on the best way to avoid this redundant code would be great!

Comment: you should do a directive

Comment: How is it redundant? What do your other usages look like?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg its all the same code as far as doing state reload on success. so in another controller it would be identical but OtherService.update instead of MyService.update

Answer (score 1):

You could put the code into the Service and just pass the `$state` in:

**MyService**

```
updateAndReload = function(val, $state){
    update(val).then(function(result) {
       if (result.Success) {
         $state.reload();
       }
       else {
         $state.go('^');
       }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.submit = MyService.updateAndReload(val, $state)
```

But this only works if it really is the exact same code every time. If there are more differences you probably just need to add more parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var commonFn = function(result) {
  if (result.Success) {
    $state.reload();
  }
  else {
    $state.go('^');
  }
}
MyService.update(val).then(commonFn);
```